# Passing SparkConf settings from the command line to Spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark

I'm trying to have spark work with Azure Blob Storage data. The way to pass credentials to it is as follows:

```
spark.conf.set(
 "fs.azure.account.key.STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net",
 "KEY")
```

Now if I set this in code, it works fine. However, I'd like to have this passed from the command line or an environment variable, so the code doesn't need to do this. (Yes, of course, I can read in the env vars, and set the conf pro grammatically but I'm looking for a way to not to have to do that).

I've tried setting an env var named fs.azure.account.key.STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net with the value KEY, and I've also tried:

```
--conf "fs.azure.account.key.STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net=KEY"
```

but it seems that spark only picks those up if the property starts with "spark.". Does anybody know how the runtime properties can be set through the environment or command line?

Answer (score 1):

In the `SparkConf` source code, the function for loading configs from system properties contains the following

`for ((key, value)<- Utils.getSystemProperties if key.startsWith("spark.")) {
      set(key, value, silent)
 }`

As you can see, it only sets the properties that start with "spark." which is consistent with your observation. You can change this code to remove this restriction and recompile spark so that your passed configuration from the command line can be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter through java command, for example

```
  private void parseArgs(String[] args) throws org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException {
    DefaultParser defaultParser = new DefaultParser();
    options = new Options();
    options.addOption("h", "help");
    options.addOption(Option.builder()
                            .longOpt("profile")
                            .desc("profile to run. (dev|azure|prod)")
                            .hasArg()
                            .build());
    options.addOption(Option.builder()
                            .longOpt("azure_storage_key")
                            .desc("azure storage key")
                            .hasArg()
                            .build());
    options.addOption(Option.builder()
                            .longOpt("develop")
                            .desc("set the environment for development.")
                            .build());
    commandLine = defaultParser.parse(options, args, true);

}
```

So when you receive

```
if (commandLine.hasOption("azure_storage_key")) {
        String key = commandLine.getOptionValue("azure_storage_key", "key");
        spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net",key)
}
```

Comment: I know I can set it programmatically with spark.conf.set. The question is about passing it in without requiring explicit code in my program. e.g. I can use --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false and the spark setting is used without code doing spark.conf.set. I'm looking for it to work like that for fs.azure.account.....

Comment: You cannot by design. Spark only allow some custom Hadoop/Hive config https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration

Comment: That's not quite correct. e.g. --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps"  can be set, which is not a hadoop config. But it appears the setting must start with "spark.".

Comment: What I mean is that it's also by design. It only allow some conf by prefix spark.